# Yiic wants to create webapp in framework folder

Tags: php, yii

I'm on linux and my home directory is:

```
public_html/yii
```

(I installed yii in a subdomain yii.domain.com)

my framework is in:

```
public_html/yii/yiiroot/framework
```

i want to create a project called demo, but it always tries to create it in the framework folder.

ie.

```
cd public_html/yii
yiiroot/framework/yiic webapp demo
```

when I run this command it asks me if I want to create a webapp in:

```
public_html/yii/yiiroot/framework/demo
```

How do I reconfigure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can just hardcode the absolute path of the webapp folder.

```
yiiroot/framework/yiic webapp ~/public_html/demo
```